# What is the equivalent of "\n\t " in string mode in re-builder?

Tags: regular-expressions

[This webpage](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/re-builder-interactive-regexp-builder) recommends being in the string mode when using re-builder, the interactive regexp builder, where one does not have to use "\" to escape special characters.

But how does one convert newline and tab characters in, say, this regexp `"\\([^\n\t '()\"]*\\)"` in read mode to string mode? This question also applies to all [characters that becomes special characters after the backslash](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression).

Comment: You can directly use `C-q tab` and `C-q C-j` instead of `\t` and `\n`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does one convert newline and tab characters

Just type them.

- <kbd>RET</kbd> types a newline
- <kbd>TAB</kbd> types a tab

> This question also applies to all characters that becomes special characters after the backslash.

If there is no special regexp syntax for a character, then you match it by typing that character, or otherwise entering it literally.  As has been mentioned by others, `quoted-insert` can be helpful here.

You can also let re-builder do it for you.  When you switch between `read` and `string` syntax, the existing regexp is converted appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Type them as usual with `TAB` and `RET` (or `C-j`), if Emacs doesn't
insert the corresponding characters for you, try `C-q TAB` and `C-q C-j` instead (*Note that `C-q`
runs the `quoted-insert` command*).

Comment: It is a good idea to use `C-q TAB` instead of `TAB` because in some situation `TAB` is replaced by spaces (e.g., indentation).